# Event change: unable to get changedfields

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event, change-data-capture

I am tring to get the list of fields that was changed in my record, based on this [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_eventbus_ChangeEventHeader.htm), I thought I should be able to retrieve the fields by:

```
trigger OpportunityChangeTrigger on OpportunityChangeEvent (after insert) {
    for (OpportunityChangeEvent event : Trigger.New) {
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;
        System.debug('### ' + JSON.serialize(header));
        System.debug('### ' + header.changedFields);
```

however when i try to save i get the error of

```
 Variable does not exist: changedFields (5:38)
```

Oddly I can loop through the recordIDs by doing:

```
for (String s: header.recordIds) {
```

The JSON that is dump from the first debug looks like:

```
{
"changeOrigin": "com/salesforce/api/rest/49.0",
"changeType": "UPDATE",
"changedFields": [
    "LastModifiedDate",
    "Loan_Amount__c"
],
"commitNumber": 115881264176,
"commitTimestamp": 1596785641000,
"commitUser": "0056F00000ARGHoQAP",
"diffFields": [],
"entityName": "Opportunity",
"nulledFields": [],
"recordIds": [
    "0061m0000031OJAAA2"
],
"sequenceNumber": 1,
"transactionKey": "00002b2f-e53b-9b50-291a-1482f318efa1"
}
```

Comment: are you at V47 or higher?

Comment: @cropredy i missed that part I was on v46, now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [EventBus.ChangeEventHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_eventbus_ChangeEventHeader.htm) clearly states that for the property `changedFields` that V47.0 is required

> A list of the fields that were changed in an update operation, including the LastModifiedDate system field. This field is empty for other operations, including record creation. This property is available in Apex saved using API version 47.0 or later.

Change the metadata for your apex class to be 47.0 or higher